# Can I get requests/responses info, on my android?

Tags: proxy, reverse-engineering, wireshark, charles-proxy, mitmproxy

I have an android and mobile app, whose API I would like to know. I've searched a lot of about proxy and the rest things, but I still can't catch some requests (it's online app, and I see, that the data was loaded, but I don't see any response with body that I need). And I don't understand, how can't I see an URL and request/response body, if my mobile app knows them and my android knows them. How can I catch 100% of requests  (and see their response) on my android? The app I'm using is somehow taking the data and displaying it to me, so I must have access to view it, am I right?

I've tried wireshark, proxyman, charles, mitmproxy and things like that on emulator, but they need me to be a developer of app that I want to proxy. I also tried Proxyman on my iOS which works fine with https requests/response (I can see them), but it's still can't fetch all requests (because I don't see needed information there)

Comment: The answer is the same no matter which proxy you use. The linked answer belongs to a question on Fiddler but the answer is the same for Charles, Mitmproxy, ...

Comment: I think it's really do!!! Thanks mate! Can you write it as an answer? I will mark it